Newer easier ways to interact with the console in Java 23+?
I have seen mentions of new classes and methods, like this, for interacting with a console in a Java app.
I cannot find a Java JEP for that on the JEP index.

tl;dr
Yes, new console methods are being previewed in Java 24 (& Java 23).
The existing Console class, and a new IO class, offer print, println, & readln methods.
The old System.out.println ( "Hello world!" ) is supplanted by the new IO.println ( "Hello world!" ).
Details
Yes, there is a series of JEPs adding features related to the console.

Java 24 (Early-Access)JEP 495: Simple Source Files and Instance Main Methods (Fourth Preview)
Java 23 (current)JEP 477: Implicitly Declared Classes and Instance Main Methods (Third Preview)

This series is part of the Paving the On-Ramp effort in recent years to make Java easier for beginner students.
java.io.IO
If successful, this series of JEPs would add a new class, java.io.IO. This class offers these methods:

static void print ( Object obj )
static void println ( Object obj )
static String readln ( String prompt )

Notice that these methods are static. So we can use them without instantiating an object.
So the familiar System.out.println ( "Hello world!" ); becomes:
import java.io.IO;
…
IO.println ( "Hello world!" );

Or, be even more brief with a static import.
import static java.io.IO.println;
…
println ( "Hello world!" );

java.io.Console
These java.io.IO methods are implemented by calling upon the Console object returned from System.console(). So that Console class gains new methods, with the same signatures.
More info
Caveat: These are preview features, subject to change or removal.
Try these out in an early-access build of Java 24 based on the OpenJDK codebase. See the early-access Javadoc for Java 24.

IO.println Personally I would have got that done in the early 90s had I been in the right place

Playing around with this for my students. I like it, but I hope they overload println() with no args to just print a newline. Super important for many of the little examples teachers use like printing n symbols in a row, etc

Ah, println() without args is in JEP 495. Perfect.
